# How do I allow a normal user to restart a supervisor group without password?

Tags: linux, debian, sudo, supervisord

I am trying to allow a user in the group `deployer` to restart a supervisor group without a password; this is the content of my `/etc/sudoers.d/deploy`:

```
%deployer ALL=(ALL:ALL) NOPASSWD:/usr/sbin/service nginx stop,/usr/sbin/service nginx start,/usr/bin/supervisorctl stop gname\:*,/usr/bin/supervisorctl start gname\:*
```

This is suppose to allow a user in the group `deployer` to restart nginx and the supervisor group `gname`. It works for nginx, but not for supervisor.

I have tried multiple combinations:

```
/usr/bin/supervisorctl stop gname,/usr/bin/supervisorctl start gname
/usr/bin/supervisorctl stop gname*,/usr/bin/supervisorctl start gname*
/usr/bin/supervisorctl stop gname\:,/usr/bin/supervisorctl start gname\:
/usr/bin/supervisorctl stop gname\:\*,/usr/bin/supervisorctl start gname\:\*
```

But I can not make it work... Why doesn't this work?

- Debian GNU/Linux 8
- Linux version 4.5.5-x86_64
- Supervisor version 3.0

Answer (score 0):

This looks like it may be due to the spaces in the commands you are allowing e.g. `supervisorctl stop gname` etc.

While I am unable to test at the minute, first I would try escaping the spaces e.g.

```
%deployer ALL=(ALL:ALL) NOPASSWD:/usr/sbin/service\ nginx\ stop,/usr/sbin/service\ nginx\ start,/usr/bin/supervisorctl\ stop\ gname\:*,/usr/bin/supervisorctl\ start\ gname\:*
```

If that fails you could put the commands into a script called `supercontrol.sh` with different cmd options for the different commands and specify `NOPASSWD` on just that script.

```
%deployer ALL=(ALL:ALL) NOPASSWD:/path/to/supercontrol.sh
```

Hope this helps.